# pipe to put underscore bottom letter angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i want get first letter and put underscore in bottom.
the code to get first letter and transform

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'underlinePrimeiraLetra'
})
export class underlinePrimeiraLetraPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string, args: any[]): string {
    if (value === null) return;
    return value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1);
  }
}
```

but for put underscore in under letter, how i can do?

if i do it

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'underlinePrimeiraLetra'
})
export class underlinePrimeiraLetraPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string, args: any[]): string {
    if (value === null) return;
    return "<u>" + value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + "</u>" + value.slice(1);
  }
}
```

not show correct:

[image]

Comment: You mean like underline the first character? Like `<u>` tag do?

Comment: yes, but i try do it, but not work...
  let value2 = `<u>${value.charAt(0)}</u>`
    return value2 + value.slice(1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with CSS only, with the `::first-letter` selector :

```css
p::first-letter {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<p>underline & capitalize my first letter !</p>
```

Comment: Have the decency to comment when you downvote please.

Comment: i have deleted the answer!!

Comment: @Chellappan you could have kept it, I only downvote to sort the answers

Answer (score 1):

**In the HTML**

```
<p *ngFor="let name of names" [innerHTML]="name | underlinePrimeiraLetra"></p>
```

**In the Pipe file**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'underlinePrimeiraLetra'
})
export class underlinePrimeiraLetraPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string, args: any[]): string {
    if (value === null) return;
    return "<u>" + value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + "</u>" + value.slice(1);
  }
}
```

Check the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ywuvgr)

**Update:**

Even this `answer is being a little bit wrong and too complicated for the need` as **@trichetriche** said, I want to let the interesting people know about how to sanatize the HTML

Below one is the sanitized code

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform, SecurityContext } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'underlinePrimeiraLetra'
})
export class underlinePrimeiraLetraPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  transform(value: string, args: any[]): string {
    if (value === null) return;
    return this._sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, "<u>" + value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + "</u>" + value.slice(1));
  }
}
```

I've updated the Stackblitz also

Comment: No need for Angular.

Comment: No need for Angular means?

Comment: That you can do it very simply with CSS.

Comment: What's the problem with above code? You are downvotng everyone's answers!!!

Comment: Yes, because no Angular code is required. I don't see the point of changing the inner HTML of some content to underline a single letter. Besides, you will need to sanitize your string before rendering it. I would have downvoted twice, but I can't.

Comment: how i can do it with css?

Comment: @DaviResio I have posted an answer about it.

Comment: @DaviResio did you try trichetriche's solution

Comment: @JavascriptLover-SKT (by the way, I don't downvote out of pleasure, I too lose points when downvoting. I do so because upvoted answers will come first. Your answer being a little bit wrong and too complicated for the need, like the other ones, should be below other better answers).

Comment: Now that you added the sanitizing part, I don't need a downvote because it answers the question (but I don't give an upvote either because it's not the best solution)

Comment: @trichetriche yeah that's correct, but want to let other `javascript / angular lovers` to know about sanitizing HTML. And your answer is super good and simple :-;